# Inserting All Data from Multiple DBF files into Multiple Tables

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyodbc, dbf

I am working on pushing data from DBF files from a UNC to a sql server DB. There are about 50 DBF files, all of which with different schemas. Now I know I can create a program and list all 50 Tables and all 50 DBF files but this is going to take forever. Is there a way to derive the DBF field names somehow to do the insert rather then going through every DBF and typing out every field name in the DBF? Here's the code I have right now that inserts records from two fields in one DBF file.

```
import pyodbc
from dbfread import DBF

# SQL Server Connection Test
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=**********;DATABASE=TEST_DBFIMPORT;UID=test;PWD=test')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
dir = 'E\\Backups\\'
table = DBF('E:\\Backups\\test.dbf', lowernames=True)
for record in table.records:
    rec1 = record['field1']
    rec2 = record['field2']
    cursor.execute ("insert into tblTest (column1,column2) values(?,?)", rec1, rec2)
    cnxn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some helpful hints using my [dbf package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf):

```
import dbf
import os

for filename in os.listdir('e:/backups'):
    with dbf.Table('e:/backups/'+filename) as table:
        fields = dbf.field_names(table)
        for record in table:
            values = list(record)
            # insert fields, values using odbc
```

If you want to transfer all fields, then you'll need to calculate the table name, the field names, and the values; some examples:

```
sql_table = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]

fields = ','.join(fields)
place_holders = ','.join(['?'] * len(fields))
values = tuple(record)

sql = "insert into %s (%s) values(%s)" % (sql_table, fields, place_holders)

curser.execute(sql, *values)
```

Comment: This is probably more of a generic python question and I have very little Python experience but during the loop, I will be doing inserts into each table. I'm assuming that there's no way to get around the insert statements for each table, which is fine, but how do I assign the values from your record list to the values in the insert statement dynamically?

Comment: @HMan06: Are you inserting only certain fields from each table, or every field from every table?

Comment: I was thinking of doing every field from every table as I guess it's easier. Either way will work and I'm going to clean up the data once it's inserted into the DB.

Comment: I attempted to test this out and ran into an issue. Apparently the DBF files I'm using have some pre-existing formatting so the insert is trying to insert values such as, u'X31A0UQYB3', u'E', datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 21, 15, 34, 31, 999000), datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 23, 13, 16, 44)

Comment: @HMan06: That's not formatting, that's the data types of the values: `unicode`, `unicode`, `datetime`, `datetime`.  Does `pyodbc` want only text and numeric values?

Comment: @HMan06:  By which I meant `u'E'` is the unicode value `E` and `datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 23, 13, 16, 44)` is the value `Sep 23, 2010 1:16:44 pm`.

Comment: Yes python only wants text and numeric values. Basically I need to insert strings into a table.

Comment: @HMan06: You mean `pyodbc`?  Python is perfectly happy to work with non-text values.  ;)  Speaking of which, will unicode be a problem, or do you have to pass bytes?